# Regex for one line

Tags: regex

my website has a URL as follows (username)/settings/. And I have other pages (username)/settings/notifications. I wanted to redirect the page (username)/settings/ to another page using Regex. However, I tried with the code below and the /notifications pages was redirected because I don't know how to restrict the regex...

first URL

```
/settings/notifications/
```

second URL (the url I want it to redirect)

```
(username)/settings/
```

code used

```
/(.*)/settings/
```

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10601203). It is text, include it as such. Additionally, questions should be self-contained. Readers should not be forced to click on a link in order to understand your question. This also makes the question useless in the future if/when [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) occurs. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on how to improve your question.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks for the warning, I corrected my question.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to match? Do you want the entire URL or do you just want the word `settings`?

Comment: @Jesse This URL on my website has previous variables, so it's random/settings/, I wanted something that was only valid for it using the (.*) but not valid for what came after /settings/.

Comment: @Jesse For example, I wanted that code not to be valid for URLs that had something after /settings/.

Comment: Your question is contradictory. The first part says *"I don't want it to be valid for the second URL"* but at the end you say *"How can I improve this code to match only the second URL?"*. Are you wanting it to be valid for the first URL or the second URL?

Comment: @Jesse Second, sorry!

Comment: Can you update your question to say that then really quickly?

Comment: @Jesse Updated, see if it's clear.

Comment: `/settings/$` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply verify that there is nothing after the final `/` character. There are a bunch of ways to do this depending on your needs. Here are the two that immediately come to mind.

The first method is to check for the end of the string using the `$` symbol. Since you only want to match it if the end of the string ends directly after `settings/`, we can use this symbol to make sure the string ends after the final `/`.

```
(.*)/settings/$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vite1q/1)

This last one won't work if for whatever reason you can have white space after the URL, so let's make one that does. We can simply put `\s*` before the `$` symbol. `\s` tells the engine to match any white space character, and the `*` symbol tells it to match between 0 and unlimited times. This combined with the `$` symbol at the end ensures that only white space (if there is any) will be matched before the end of the string.

```
(.*)/settings/\s*$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/N7OxKf/1)

Comment: Thankss so much!